# Python: subprocess.communicate(): ValueError with print() function but not "print" builtin

Tags: python, printing, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to run a C program from Python with the subprocess module, capturing its output in a variable. the code looks like this:

```
process = Popen(["myprog", str(length), filename], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
#wait for the process
result = process.communicate()
end=time()
print result
```

The above code works - `result` is shown as a 2-tuple of `myprog`'s stdout output and stderr output (as strings).

... *however* if I change `print result` to `print(result)`...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(result)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I'm completely stumped here, I don't even know where to start trying to explain this! Of course, my program works anyway, but I'd really like to know why that's happened, and hopefully it will be an interesting question.

Comment: would you please show us the whole Python and the whole C program?

Answer (score 4):

This is *not* a Python problem. You have a problem with `myprog`, not Python.

In Python 2, the difference between `print something` and `print(something)` is null and void. There is *no* difference at all because the Python compiler sees the parenthesis as a no-op and the resulting byte-code is exactly the same:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo(): print 'bar'
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('bar')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> def foo(): print('bar')
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('bar')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```